# Obtain the size of an anonymous NSView

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nsview

Seems like a simple question but the answer *seems* nontrivial.

Problem Statement:

I have a container view that obtains a subview from somewhere and I want to know what size it is or could be.

In springs and struts world, I would have just checked the autoResizeMask and if it wasn't resizable, then check the frame of the view when it was provided to the containerView. If it was resizable in some direction, I would have considered the view unbounded in that direction.

Now enter auto layout. Under auto layout, I would check the fitting size. If the fitting size returns a non-zero number for some size/height, then that is the smallest the view should be without violating any constraints. If it is zero, then I should consider the view to be unbounded (large or small). Yes there is intrinsic size, but it has the same problem.

So the question is, if I load a view from some random nib, how does a generic container view know which method it should use? That is, if a nib is completely unaware of auto layout, intrinsic size *always* return 0,0 regardless of the value of the autoresizemask (at least in all my tests). And the last thing it seems like I should do is use the frame size and check the autoresize mask on a view loaded from a nib that is auto layout aware as there is no guarantee that the initial frame is either not the optimum size nor not already violating the view's constraints.

So the answer is *not* check the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints as the documentation clearly states that the provided view in the nib should not set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property if "you are not the person who specifies a view’s relation to its container" which is clearly the case here.

Am I missing something or is there a well known work around that folks seem to be using?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why exactly can't you use the view's frame **after** autolayout or springs/struts or whatever mechanism resizes the view has done its job?

Comment: The problem is that comes late in the drawing and the container view is the one doing the resizing. That is, if you want to know the size of the view doing what you describe, then you would have needed to already have placed it.

Comment: Don't understand. '*..comes late in the drawing*' - when drawing takes place, all views are at their final positions with final dimensions.

Comment: The generic container that i am referring to is the one that is doing the placement of the subview. To do that, it needs to know what size the subview could be _before_ it places it (sets up constraints etc). If I am reading your post right, you are suggesting that I use the size after its placed in the super view and layout system has sized it correctly. The issue is that placing the subview in the superview is the task that needs the subview's size.

Comment: Well, otherwise it sounds like you'll have to re-implement autolayout on your own..